# Alternative to WiX Patch

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, patch

I have an MSI, which adds a registry key, installs and starts some services, installs a file and so on. Now, there is a requirement to update one file and add a new file. I know we can create a Patch by creating a difference / transform. But in my second MSI, I only want to include these 2 files (the updated one and the new one) and not the other files, probably like a HotFix. I don't want to create a Patch. I did try to create a separate MSI but with the same UpgradeCode but with a different Product ID and a different version. But this creates a new entry in Programs and Features. Also, while uninstalling this new MSI, it does rollback the new file, but it doesn't rollback the modified file (this file was originally created by the first MSI and modified by the second one). At least if it is able to rollback and restore the state during uninstallation, it would have been great. But it is not rolling back the modified file properly.Has anyone come across this scenario? If so, have you been able to find a solution without a Patch? Please help.

Comment: What are your *reasons* for avoiding Patch since, as you yourself seem to be saying, it seems like an ideal use case for it. If there are certain technical constraints, *knowing what they are* will help avoid other suggestions that turn out also to be unsuitable.

Comment: My client wants it this way and there is a reason. The patch may contain other changes also which he is not interested in.

Comment: ...then create a patch which only has the changes that the client wants.

Comment: "My client wants it this way and there is a reason. The patch may contain other changes also which he is not interested in." This is a specific patch though. Patches are often small. The developer of the patch ultimately has final say as to what it changes. In other words, this sounds like a trust issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to update an installed product: a patch, a major upgrade and a minor upgrade. Although you can create a new MSI that replaces some of the files in an existing product what you are actually doing is sharing them in the same way that Microsoft Dlls (for example) are shared between many different products. (Unless you use the same component Ids and share properly you are more likely to break the product instead of updating it.) This is why you see that behavior of preserving files.

The idea that the patch may contain "contain other changes also which he is not interested in" should not be an issue. You create the patch so that it contains only those changes. It will contain other changes only if you put them in the MSI file when you create the patch.

Adding files during a patch can be tricky because there are some rules involved. 
The safest thing to do is a major upgrade when adding new files.

So the choces are:

1. A patch that contains only the required updates.
2. A major upgrade, which is the complete new MSI file that upgrades the product.
3. A minor update which again is the complete new MSI file with the same ProductCode, incremented version, only minor hotfix changes, install with a special command line that includes REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus

Only the patch can be made to include just the changes required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response, Phil. But for creating a Patch, we need the transform / difference. So, let's say, if my original MSI has 100 files and the new MSI has only 3 files, when I do a transform, won't the 97 remaining files also get into the transform and hence become a part of the patch? Please help me understand.

Comment: You build an MSI which is identical to the original with all the files, same ProductCode, incremented version, and the few updated files. The patch is the difference between the two MSI files.